# How to get License Expiration and Expired count from office365 api

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I am trying to use the API (and graph explorer) capture **Total license count**, **Total license utilization**, **License Expiration days left**, and **License Expired count** for all relevant Microsoft products, especially Office365.

The first 2 I think I have in the bag, the last 2 I am running into serious problems with.

Please help.

Comment: Could you explain what the "serious problems" are. There is not enough info here.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I was having a lot of trouble finding what calls will have that data an/or how to acquire that data indirectly via some calculation or expression of other values from other calls

Comment: sorry for not replying here. Did you get this resolved?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: @AdilZ: I am facing same issue. Not able to find any APIs for expiration. Did you find any way?